# Getting error C2248 while trying to initialize MFC CCriticalSection

Tags: c++, mfc

I have been trying to fix/find a solution for an hour or so for this.
Basically I have:

```
CCriticalSection pCS;
```

inside a class declaration, and then I use a CSingleLock like this:

```
CSingleLock pSL(&pCS);
pSL.Lock();
*Stuff happening here*
pSL.Unlock();
```

to lock and unlock the pCS. But initializing the CriticalSection seems to always end up in this:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxmt.h(82): error C2248: 'CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(535) : see declaration of 'CObject::operator ='
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(509) : see declaration of 'CObject'
This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'CSyncObject &CSyncObject::operator =(const CSyncObject &)'
```

I have 4 worker threads in the program and I'm sending them the pointer to the class where the CCriticalSection is, and the threads are working on the CCriticalSection, aswell as the main thread. The threads use the pointer of the class to use the CSingleLock that uses the CCriticalSection.

For your information, the code also includes Direct2D but that shouldn't be relevant.

Some help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Just tried to make a new project with just:

```
#include <afxmt.h>
```

in it. It gave me exceptions. Is that normal? I'm using VC++ 2010 Professional.

SOLVED:

Had a CEvent up there aswell, so I thought I'd make it into a pointer as well, and whaddya you know. It fixed that problem. Now there's an afxmt.h file giving me exceptions.

Comment: The error indicates that you're trying to make a copy of a `CCriticalSection`, but that type is non-copyable. You need to show more code, namely, the code attempting to perform said copy.

Comment: Any chance at all that the object that *holds* this critical section (pCS in your code) being copied in any way ? It seems as though the  copy-constructor for CCriticalSection is being referenced. If you're not explicitly copying the crit-sec, are you ever explicitly or implicitly copying the object that holds it? hide the copy-constructor of your class (make it private) and if it breaks compilation somewhere thats you're fail-point).

Comment: I'm only declaring the variable, and then using the CSingleLocks to use the CCriticalSection. There's no point in the code where the CriticalSection is being copied. I changed the CCriticalSection pCS to CCriticalSection* pCS and it's still not working.

Comment: Just made the copy constructor of my class private, no effect. Still complaining about the CObject.

Comment: @Nooobody : I guarantee that the error messages show you what line of _your_ code is triggering the problem. Look at the Output window, not the Errors window, and find which lines of _your_ code it mentions.

Comment: ^ http://imageshack.us/a/img687/7088/outputu.png

Comment: @Nooobody : That looks like a pretty tall scrollbar. ;-] Are there any other errors above that one?

Comment: There's only around 27 warnings about conversions from UINT to float may cause loss of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a CEvent up there aswell, so I thought I'd make it into a pointer as well, and whaddya you know. It fixed that problem. Now there's an afxmt.h file giving me exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple threads to synchronize on a CRITICAL_SECTION you can share a pointer to the same critical section but you can't actually make a copy of the CRITICAL_SECTION.

Comment: I'm sharing a pointer to a class that has the pointer to the CriticalSection, so there's no copying done. Commented the other threads away from the code, no effect.